# Facebook Graph API: search people by city

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find people either from particular city or who live in that city. Is there an API for this purpose?

When I use Facebook page, I can type in "People who live in Rome, Italy" (which is translated to URL https://www.facebook.com/search/115353315143936/residents/present) and it shows me all people who currently live in Rome. Using web page I can also search people by name and then add additional filter by city.

Can I do something similar with Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

You can only search by name with the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search - there is no way to get the same kind of search than on facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

you can add  center and distance in the query
this comes from the documentation,   you can change the type to type=user

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q=coffee&
    type=place&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```